# How can I run selenium UI tests on a grid from docker container?

Tags: selenium, docker, capybara

I'm trying to get my test runner application completely Dockerized. I use the public hub and node images to create a Selenium Grid which works fine - I can run my tests locally against the Dockerized Grid. Now, all I need to do is Dockerize my test app code and run it against the Grid. I created a docker-compose file to setup the grid and then run the test code. Unfortunately, when the tests run from the Docker container they seem to be unable to connect to the hub. I checked the logs of the test runner container and I see some output from the first step of the test. It then hangs there for around a minute and outputs the following:

```
Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

I shelled into the docker test runner container and was able to ping the hub from there so I believe the test runner can talk to the hub. I specified my driver configuration like so:

```
Capybara.register_driver :remote_hub_chrome do |app|
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
    caps.version = "59.0.3071.115"
    caps.platform = "LINUX"
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        :browser => :chrome,
        :url => "http://hub-container:4444/wd/hub",
        :desired_capabilities => caps
    )
end
```

As you can see, it will try to hit the hub-container domain, which it should be able to since I can ping it from within the container.

I do not see any log info on the browser node container so it seems like it wasn't even attempted to be reached. I am able to run the exact same test from my local machine outside of the docker container. Only difference is I have to change hub-container to localhost since I'm not running from within the container anymore.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't get the test to run from within a docker container?

Compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - ui-test

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    ports:
      - "5900"
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    networks:
      - ui-test

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    ports:
      - "5900"
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    networks:
      - ui-test

  test-runner:
    image: test-runner
    depends_on:
      - hub
      - chrome
      - firefox
    networks:
      - ui-test

networks:
  ui-test:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Post your compose file

Comment: added compose file

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things can go wrong with such a complex setup. I currently made it work without the Grid, after many lost hours of debugging. Since you are posting Chrome setup, here is how I managed to make it run:

```
 caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions' => { 'args' =>
      ['--start-maximized', '--disable-infobars',
       '--no-sandbox', '--whitelisted-ips'] }
 )
```

So you should add those two `'--no-sandbox', '--whitelisted-ips'` in order to make the `chromedriver` binary to work with Docker/Remote setup. Also you can check if your binary actually has permissions via `ls -la`, if not try run `chmod +x chromedriver` and `chmod 777 chromedriver` (do the same for the `geckodriver`, which  should be placed in `user/bin` according to Mozilla dos). If you still have issues with the later, You have to follow [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver):

> "Even though the project has been renamed to GeckoDriver, many of the selenium clients look for the old name.
>    You need to rename the binary file to 'wires' (the old name) and ensure it is executable."

Last thing that can tell you, if there are problems with the driver executables is to run them as standalone, just got the their location (for `geckodriver` is `/usr/bin`) and start it like so `./geckodriver`, the output should help you catch errors if such are present.

In case your nodes don't have displays - you need to use `headless` or `xvfb` setup, be sure to troubleshoot this as well. Display ports should be accessible too.

Comment: Do I need headless or xvfb if I'm running the tests on another machine?

Comment: Yes, if the machine has no display, as containers don't usually have such.

Comment: But why? I am running the tests remotely, all I should need is the commandline. To be clear, the hub and nodes have the display. The test runner is supposed to just send the tests to the hub but it's failing at that.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer, it might help others in future :) Actually only nodes need display, hub can be on a different host. Are you behind proxies in that case? Another thing to consider is that docker containers have different IP than the host, they are on. I see u r mentioning localhost. So did u bind container ports to the host and expose those?

Comment: Yes and I can run my tests against the hub just fine. The only problem is when I put my tests into a container, then they fail to run against the hub (or fail to perform the first step of the test).

Answer (score 0):

Update the `:url` option in your driver configuration to `:url => "http://hub:4444/wd/hub"`. The hostname must match the name of the `hub` service defined in your compose file.

Comment: yes I've tried both ways. I had previously started the hub with container name hub-container. Either way, I can ping hub and hub-container successfully from the test runner container. Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Barodapride What does your `test-runner` Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: No, the hub logs say the grid is up and running and that it registered a couple nodes. The node logs end with "The node is registered to the hub and ready to use" so I'm assuming they are good. I am assuming the Dockerized grid is working fine since I can run my tests locally by sending them to the grid. Only difference I can think within the Container test runner is the geckodriver/chromedriver setup there. Not sure what else the problem could be.